# serve content based on vistor lan vs wan?

Tags: html

I'm guessing this isn't possible, because my Google-fu isn't that bad, yet I can't find anyone doing it, anyone wanting to do it, or any hints on how I might do it.  Probably because it is a very bad idea, dumb idea, or so super simple that I should already know how without wasting your time.

I'm just trying to build a very simple landing page on my own webserver so I have links to the various services' web admin pages that I want to go to without having to remember the different port numbers.  99% of the time, I'm doing this on my own lan, but sometimes I access over the Internet.

Right now, my landing page might have a link to 192.168.1.2:3939 for example.  I can access the landing page from outside by going to mydomain.com, but then my link still goes to 192.168 blah blah blah.

I'd like it to be the local lan link when I'm accessing from within the lan, but automagically replace the 192.168.1.2 with mydomain.com when I'm accessing from outside.

Possible?  Stupid?  Is there a better way I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Replacing '192.168.1.2' with 'mydomain.com' when you're outside is not possible since it points to somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply configure your LAN DNS to point your domain to `192.168.1.2`.  Then, you can simply use the hostname everywhere.

Comment: Ha!  I feel stupid now for asking, but grateful because I got the answer.  I really should have thought of that myself, but I didn't.  Thank you!